# Automated Action to Add Users as Followers Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

i need to make a Automated Action on Odoo 12 to auto add the 3 chosen users as followers on create of contact.

[image]

Contact Manager = **Field name:** user_id

L2 Manager = **Field name:** x_studio_l2_manager

L3 Manager = **Field name:** x_studio_l3_manager

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install **Automated Action Rules** module for model automation, you will find the menu in Settings >> Debug Turn on >> Technical >> Automation >> Automated Actions, create a new automation action, Model: Contact, Trigger condition: On creation, Action to do: Add followers, Select followers,

[image: Add automatic followers]

This will assign static followers to the newly created contacts. But for dynamic followers, you have to execute python code:

```
record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=[record.user_id.partner_id.id, record.x_studio_l2_manager.id, record.x_studio_l3_manager.id])
```

Remember this is assuming `x_studio_l3_manager`, `x_studio_l2_manager` are `res.partner` type field and `user_id` is `res.users` type field. If not, update your question with which types of related fields are those. Remember, if the fields are `res.users`, you have to use `record.x_studio_l2_manager.partner_id.id, record.x_studio_l3_manager.partner_id.id` because `res.users` table id will not be always same as `res.partner` table id for a particular user.

You can unfollow existing followers using following code:

```
record.message_unsubscribe(partner_ids=record.message_partner_ids.ids)
```

To perform this, you have add server action that will execute python code, add the code to the server action and run that server action selecting the records.

Comment: First of all Thanks very much for the solution, i also have L2 Manager, L3 Manager `res.users` so is working perfect. One question more, when i update the followers delete the old users followers with the new (update the follow list). How can i do that?

Comment: Updated answer.