# Automated action to add multiple users as followers in Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I created a custom module where you can link multiple contacts in a many2many field and I want to automatically add them all as a follower. I've read this article:

[Automated Action to Add Users as Followers Odoo 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435440/automated-action-to-add-users-as-followers-odoo-12)

Adding followers works fine, but only when the fields have **ONE** user or partner in it. In my installation these are many2many fields. When I add *more then one* user or partner in one of the fields, the code crashes.

Do I need to change something in this code when I want to add more then 1 contact or user in one of the fields?

I have this python code in my automated action:

```
record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=[record.field1.id, record.field2.partner_id.id, record.field3.partner_id.id])
```

> field1 = partner

> field2 & field3 = user

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `.id` to get id of records when there is multiple record, you have to use `.ids` which returns a list of record ids. So you code will have to changed into:

```
field1_ids = record.field1.ids
field2_ids = record.field2.mapped('partner_id').ids
field3_ids = record.field3.mapped('partner_id').ids
record.message_subscribe(partner_ids=field1_ids+field2_ids+field3_ids)
```

So the main issue with your code was, you were trying to access field where the record could be multiple (as `many2many`), but in Odoo ORM you can not do that, it will always give `Expected Singletone` error for multiple records.